# Total usage of a shared directory across multiple users - LINUX

Tags: linux, shell, directory

I am trying to get the total bytes used by a shared folder across multiple users.

I have got this within a larger script:

```
cd /home/user1/SharedFolder/
echo "Total for user1 : "
ls -lrt | awk '{ Total1 += $5 }; END { print Total1 " bytes"}'

cd /home/user2/SharedFolder/
echo "Total for user2 : "
ls -lrt | awk '{ Total2 += $5 }; END { print Total2 " bytes"}'
```

This allows me to view the bytes that are available in each folder individually. I am unsure if this is even the correct method to getting my desired result.

The problem I am having, is getting the **total** amount from **all** users that contain the folder (The Number of users may vary)

I am fairly new to using Linux, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lesson is to use the right tool for the job: to count up the size of all the files in a directory, use [`du`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/du.1.html). Also, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
# variable "homeDirs" will be an associative array
declare -A homeDirs

# read the /etc/passwd file, and map each user to the home directory
while IFS=: read -ra entry; do
    homeDirs["${entry[0]}"]="${entry[5]}"
done < /etc/passwd

# loop over all the users
for user in "${!homeDirs[@]}"; do
    dir="${homeDirs[$user]}/SharedFolder"
    # if that user has a shared folder
    if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
        # find the total size
        totalSize=$(du -sb "$dir" | awk '{print $1}')
        # and output the information
        printf "Total for user %s: %d\n" "$user" "$totalSize"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I'm still get used to all the tools and functions and this really helped.